# Centering text works in full screen browser but when resizing or in phone view it disturbs the look as shown in fiddles

Tags: html, css, media-queries, margin, centering

Okay beginner here- trying to get this site to look good no matter what screen size.

This is the site page that works no matter the screen size:
https://jsfiddle.net/garixakor/j0xck25v/1/

I tried to center one of the paragraphs so it looks better in desktop view and when I do the text no longer fits neatly in phone size or when making the desktop browser smaller.

```
P.blocktext {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 20em
}  

<p class="blocktext">Step back in time etc etc....
```

This change is shown in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/garixakor/5Lo4rtkc/

I am wondering if using media queries as in: if the screen size is the screen is 992x or more the centering is applied is possible or if there are other solutions or if I need to find a way around centering in this manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `max-width: 100%`. With just your `width` value if the screen width gets smaller than `20em` the text container will flow outside the viewport and not wrap the text.

By setting `max-width` to `100%` it makes sure that the text container cant be wider than the parent container.

```css
P.blocktext {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 20em;
    max-width: 100%;
}

P.para {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70em;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```